# How to include chart.js charts in htmltopdf?

Tags: symfony, chart.js, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I'm using chart.js to render charts in my html page. I have used knpSnappyBundle to render html to pdf. But the charts are not rendered. I know it's due to js delay. But couldn't find the exact solution. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: i had same issues with several js ibraries and wkhtml , if you are sure that it is the js delay, dont you know where to configure it or what is your problem?

Comment: According to [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) there is `--enable-javascript` with a descriptor: `Wait some milliseconds for javascript finish (default 200)`